# Forwarding state vs forwarding props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with forwarding state from parent to child component, these 2 components are class components. 
When forwarding state from parent to child component, I want to use state showModal variable in child component as show as state variable:

```
 this.state = {
     show: this.props.show
 }
```

This variable is being used to active the modal.
When I use it as this.props.show, the state has been forwarded to child component, and updated, but when I use props in this.state in child component it hasn't been updated. Has anyone idea where the problem is?

First - Parent component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Modal from './UI/Modal';

    class EnteredBooks extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                enteredBook: this.props.enteredBook,
                showModal: false
            }
        }

        detailsHandler = () => {
            this.setState({
                showModal: true
            })
        }

        render() {
            let show =  this.state.showModal;
            return (
                <div>
                     <div className="product">
                         <img src="{this.props.enteredWatch.bookUrl}" />
                         <p>{this.props.enteredWatch.bookType}</p>
                         <p>euro{this.props.enteredWatch.bookPrice}</p>
                         <button 
                             className="details-button"
                             onClick={this.detailsHandler}
                                >
                                    Details
                         </button>
                         <Modal show={this.state.showModal} watch={this.state.enteredWatch} />
                         <button className="buy-button">Buy</button>
                      </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default EnteredWatches;
```

Second - Child component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './Modal.css';

class Modal extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

        this.state = {
            book: this.props.book,
            show: this.props.show
        }
    }
return(
        <div>
             <div className="Modal"
                    style={{
                        transform: this.state.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                        opacity: this.state.show ? '1':'0'
                    }}>

                    <img src={this.state.book.bookUrl} />
                    <p>{this.state.book.bookType}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.book.watchUrl}</p>
                    <button className="details-button">Details</button>
                    <button className="buy-button">Buy</b
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Modal;
```

Comment: That is because `constructor` function runs only once here. So even if the updated state is passed to child component, the child component's state does not update because `constructor` function does not run again. Why don't you directly use it from `props`?

Comment: I will do :), I have forgotten that constructor only run once before loading the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`constructor` runs only once. It's suitable for calculating initial state. But this case is what `getDerivedStateFromProps` hook is for. It allows to calculate a state from props every time a component is updated, including initialization:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  return {
        book: props.book,
        show: props.show
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited some parts of your code.I am not sure that you are asking this but hope it will enlight you for your problem.

First - Parent component:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import Modal from './UI/Modal';

class EnteredBooks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      enteredBook:"",
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  detailsHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
      enteredBook: this.props.enteredBook
    })
  }

  render() {
    let show = this.state.showModal;
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      div className = "product" >
      <
      img src = "{this.props.enteredWatch.bookUrl}" / >
      <
      p > {
        this.props.enteredWatch.bookType
      } < /p> <
      p > euro {
        this.props.enteredWatch.bookPrice
      } < /p> <
      button className = "details-button"
      onClick = {
        this.detailsHandler
      } >
      Details <
      /button> <
      Modal show = {
        this.state.showModal
      }
      watch = {
        this.state.enteredWatch
      }
      /> <
      button className = "buy-button" > Buy < /button> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

export default EnteredWatches;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Second - Child component:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import classes from './Modal.css';

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      book: "",
      show: ""
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const {
      book,
      show
    }: this.props;
    if (book !== props.book || show !== props.show) {
      this.setState({
        book: props.book,
        show: props.show
      });
    }
  }

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    div className = "Modal"
    style = {
      {
        transform: this.state.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
        opacity: this.state.show ? '1' : '0'
      }
    } >

    <
    img src = {
      this.state.book.bookUrl
    }
    /> <
    p > {
      this.state.book.bookType
    } < /p> <
    p > {
      this.state.book.watchUrl
    } < /p> <
    button className = "details-button" > Details < /button> <
    button className = "buy-button" > Buy < /b < /
    div > <
    /div>
  );
}
}
```

> PS : Also you can use componentWillReceiveProps(props) event for the
>   parent component.